# Android Fragment Orientation Causes Attach Issues

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-orientation

Hello everyone I have a question on rotating fragments and restoring them after detaching them. Currently I have three fragments: Fragment_Data, Fragment_Log, and Fragment_Control. My problem is if I rotate Fragment_Data, then detach and add Fragment_Log, then detach Fragment_Log and attempt to attach Fragment Data it fails to reattach. If I keep the device vertical and repeat the same steps the fragments don't have any issues reattaching. I try to detach, add, and attach the fragments in my PanelManager method.

What exactly is going one during the lifecycle of the Fragment_Data that causes issues when trying to reattach?

**MainActivty.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, FragmentControl.ButtonSetListener{

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentControlTransction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
FragmentTransaction fragmentDataTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

FragmentControl fragmentControl = new FragmentControl();
FragmentData fragmentData = new FragmentData();
FragmentLog fragmentLog = new FragmentLog();
FragmentGraph fragmentGraph = new FragmentGraph();

//Create Fragment Manager
FragmentManager panelManager = getFragmentManager();

//Boolean values for panels
boolean data_panel = true;      //True because it is the first panel created in the View; id = 1
boolean log_panel = false;      //id = 2
boolean graph_panel = false;    //id = 3

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
    // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
    // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        return;
    }

    //Generate Fragment_Data and Fragment_Control Panels
    //These are the first two panels introduced into the app
    fragmentControlTransction.add(R.id.fragment_control_panel, fragmentControl, "control");
    fragmentControlTransction.commit();

    fragmentDataTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_data_panel, fragmentData, "data");
    fragmentDataTransaction.commit();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.data_log) {
        PanelManager(2);
    } else if (id == R.id.data_graph) {
        PanelManager(3);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
        PanelManager(1);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

private void PanelManager(int panel_id){

    if(panel_id == 1){
        //detach any panel attached to the fragment_data_panel
        panelManager.beginTransaction().detach(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_data_panel)).commit();
        //Switch to data panel since it already exists
        panelManager.beginTransaction().attach(fragmentData).commit();

    } else if(panel_id == 2){
        //detach any panel attached to the fragment_data_panel
        panelManager.beginTransaction().detach(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_data_panel)).commit();
        //Switch to log panel
        if(log_panel == false){
            //If log panel is false, create log_panel for the first time
            log_panel = true;
            panelManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_data_panel, fragmentLog).commit();
        } else {
            //Log_panel exists, so just attach fragment back
            panelManager.beginTransaction().attach(fragmentLog).commit();
        }

    } else if(panel_id == 3){
        //detach any panel attached to the fragment_data_panel
        panelManager.beginTransaction().detach(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_data_panel)).commit();
        //Switch to graph panel
        if(graph_panel == false){
            //If log panel is false, create graph_panel for the first time
            graph_panel = true;
            panelManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_data_panel, fragmentGraph).commit();
        } else {
            //Log_panel exists, so just attach fragment back
            panelManager.beginTransaction().attach(fragmentGraph).commit();
        }
    }

}

//Call updateList method in FragmentLog to update ListView
@Override
public void app_log_update(String data, int icon) {
    FragmentLog fragmentLog = (FragmentLog)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_data_panel);
    fragmentLog.updateList(data, icon);
}
```

}

**FragmentData.java**

```
public class FragmentData extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

public EditText message_text;
public TextView display_message;

public Button button;
public String return_message = null;

boolean has_text_entered = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        return_message = savedInstanceState.getCharSequence("savedText").toString();
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_data, container, false);

    button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.set_text_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);

    display_message = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.display_message);
    display_message.setText("This is a temp statement");
    if(return_message != null){
        display_message = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.display_message);
        display_message.setText(return_message);
    }

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    has_text_entered = true;
    message_text = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text_message);
    String message = message_text.getText().toString();

    display_message = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.display_message);
    display_message.setText(message);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    TextView text = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.display_message);
    CharSequence userText = text.getText();
    if(userText != null){outState.putCharSequence("savedText", userText);}
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}
```

}

Thank you for the help everyone!

Comment: 1)  Why do you "detach and add Fragment_Log, then detach Fragment_Log"...why so many operations on Fragment_Log?  Is something happening in between that may be important?  2)  You say it "fails to attach".  What is the error you are seeing?  Anything in the debug logs?  Or it just doesn't appear on the screen?

Comment: Im trying to switch between fragments because each fragment is displaying some information relative to our robot. I'm detaching because I need to have access to the fragment even if it is not being shown. Im not getting any errors sadly, when I go to attach Fragment_Data it fails to appear on the screen after said trail of actions.